# PowerBI - visual with custom sorting and showing top 10 values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset similar to the below

| Description | ML Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ML3: Big red house | ML3 | 25 |
| ML1: Small circle | ML1 | 10 |
| blue bike |  | 30 |
| ML1: office chair | ML1 | 100 |
| ML5: yellow keyboard | ML5 | 250 |

I am looking to have a table visual that includes any entries with an ML category of 1-5. I want to sort this visual on an ML code hierarchy e.g. ML1>ML2>ML3 etc. If there is more than 1 entry with the same ML code then I would like to sort by value highest to lowest. i.e. an ML1 entry with value of 100 would appear above an ML1 entry with value of 10.

After the visual has been sorted I want to only show the top 10 entries based on this sorting method. My ideal outcome for the above data set would be:

| Description | ML Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ML1: office chair | ML1 | 100 |
| ML1: Small circle | ML1 | 10 |
| ML3: Big red house | ML3 | 25 |
| ML5: yellow keyboard | ML5 | 250 |

This visual will be linked to a filter that may exclude some of the entries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - cannot seem to workout a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
MLFilter = LEFT('Table'[ML Category], 2)

OrderColumn = CONCATENATE('Table'[ML Category], 1000000 - 'Table'[Value])

FilterColumnForTop10 =
RANKX (
    FILTER ( 'Table', LEFT ( 'Table'[ML Category], 2 ) = "ML" ),
    'Table'[OrderColumn],
    'Table'[OrderColumn],
    asc
)
```

Add MLFilter to "Filters on this visual" and filter it to "ML".

Add FilterColumnForTop10 to "Filters on this visual" and filter it to "is less than" = 11.

In the Fields blade, select the Description column and change its "Sort by column" to OrderColumn.

**Assumptions:**

My primary assumption is that your question is accurate.  For example:

> I have a dataset similar to the below

If the data in the table that follows is from a visualization, not from the source data, you may not get the same results.  Likewise, if *Value* is an explicit measure, that could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is this code to be added as a measure or as a new column in the data?